# Ordering faceted dotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

Here is a faceted dotplot that I created with the following code (data in `dput` format provided at the end of the post).

```
ggplot(na.omit(df), aes(x = N, y = journal, group = journal, colour = studyType)) + 
geom_segment(aes(yend = journal), xend=0, colour="grey50") +
geom_point(alpha = .8, size = 4) + 
scale_color_manual(values = cp) + 
theme_bw() +
facet_grid(.~studyType) + 
theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

My interest now is to reorder the rows (Y-axis), so they are in descending order based on the overall N, computed as a sum across the facets.  So, the journal BJoSW would be listed first, then H&SW would be second, and so forth.  After reviewing other posts on the topic, the solution seems to involve reorder y variable `journal` using the overall summary variable.

```
j.order <- df$journal[order(df$N.sort, decreasing = TRUE)]
df$journal <- factor(df$journal, levels = j.order)
```

This is producing an warning message (duplicated levels in factors are deprecated), so it is obviously not right.  Although the figure is coming closer to what I am wanting, the `ggplot` call is also giving me warning message on duplicated levels.  So, I'm guessing that I don't have my data set up properly or how I am handling missing values.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
structure(list(journal = structure(c(43L, 43L, 35L, 35L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 37L, 37L, 47L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 48L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 8L, 8L, 45L, 45L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 26L, 26L, 
39L, 39L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 49L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 28L, 28L, 33L, 33L, 
41L, 41L, 50L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("BJoSW", "BJoSW", "BJoSW", 
"BJoSW", "JoESW", "JoESW", "JoESW", "Ch&S", "Ch&S", "H&SW", "H&SW", 
"H&SW", "C&FSW", "C&FSW", "C&FSW", "CSWJ", "CSWJ", "CSWJ", "CSWJ", 
"C&ASWJ", "C&ASWJ", "C&ASWJ", "IntJoSW", "IntJoSW", "IntJoSW", 
"EJoSW", "EJoSW", "InSW", "InSW", "Affl", "Affl", "Affl", "JoBSW", 
"JoBSW", "AdviSW", "AdviSW", "Aret", "Aret", "FmiS", "FmiS", 
"JoCP", "JoCP", "AdmiSW", "AdmiSW", "CJoSW", "CJoSW", "ASW&PR", 
"CSWR", "IndJoSW", "JoE&CDiSW"), class = "factor"), studyType = c("quasi", 
"sr", "quasi", "rct", "quasi", "rct", "sr", "quasi", "rct", "rct", 
"meta", "quasi", "rct", "sr", "rct", "quasi", "rct", "sr", "quasi", 
"rct", "sr", "quasi", "rct", "quasi", "sr", "meta", "quasi", 
"rct", "sr", "quasi", "rct", "quasi", "rct", "quasi", "rct", 
"sr", "meta", "quasi", "rct", "sr", "quasi", "rct", "quasi", 
"rct", "quasi", "rct", "quasi", "meta", "quasi", "rct"), N = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 6L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L), N.sort = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 14L, 14L, 14L)), .Names = c("journal", 
"studyType", "N", "N.sort"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Try (not tested) `j.order <- unique(df$journal[order(df$N.sort, decreasing = TRUE)])`. Idea is to get unique of journals order them by N then assign it to `j.order`, this way we will not have duplicated factor levels.

Comment: @zx8754:  That gives me the `duplicated levels in factors` warning message, too.

Comment: Just tested it, `j.order <- unique(df$journal[order(df$N.sort, decreasing = TRUE)])
df$journal <- factor(df$journal, levels = j.order)`, it works, run the ggplot, you will see that `BJoSW` will be at the bottom and `JoE&CDiSW` will be at the top.

Comment: @zx8754 -- my bad, you were right.  It works - please put into an answer so I can credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
j.order <- unique(df$journal[order(df$N.sort, decreasing = TRUE)])
df$journal <- factor(df$journal, levels = j.order)
```

note: a bit in a rush, will update later with more explanation...

**EDIT:**

The problem is the existing data.frame had duplicated levels in it. See:

```
#Existing levels from posted dput data.frame
table(duplicated(levels(df$journal)))
#FALSE  TRUE 
#   22    28
```

We need to fix two things, make unique levels, and order them by the number variable `N.sort`.

```
#make unique order based on N.sort
j.order <- unique(as.character(df$journal)[order(df$N.sort, decreasing = TRUE)])

#reassign journal as factor with new levels
df$journal <- factor(df$journal, levels = j.order)
```

Ordered plot:
[image]